# Avoid ranking all matching documents in elasticsearch search query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having Elasticsearch index with multi-millions of documents. I am running a following search query.

```
POST testIndex/_search?size=200
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(title:QA Manager OR title:QA Lead) AND (skills:JIRA OR skills:Software Development OR skills:Test Case)"
    }
  }
}
```

Even if we have passed the limit with `size=200`, it seems Elasticsearch is doing ranking for all the matching documents and bringing the top 200 with the highest rank.

Is there a way we can limit ranking? meaning do ranking on max 1000 matching documents only?

Comment: Ranking work like a sort, so es has to consider the whole data. If you dont need any ranking, use filter inside your query (will remove all the score), you can also create your own ranking using a function score.

Answer (score 1):

ES will consider your all data for search and ranking that is how Elasticsearch work. What basically do is, It executes your query in 2 phases, one is `query` and the second is `fetch`.

In Query Phase, it executes your query in all shades and get document `id` and `score` from each shard and return to requesting node. So in your scenario as size is set to `200`, it will get 200 documents id from each shard and return to requesting node.

On requesting node, all the document id and score are merged and sorted based on score and select top document based on `size` param.

In Fetch phase, the actual docs are retrieved from individual shards where they reside based on ID which are selected in Query Phase and Results are returned to the client.

If you don't want to calculate score for some of your query, then you can move that query to the `filter` clause in `bool` query.

Comment: do you mean there isn't a way to limit total documents on which elastic search do ranking?

Comment: Yes, there is no way. but why you want to limit it ? If you limit it to 10k or 100k then there is high chance that you will miss relevant document from result.

Comment: I am having total 550 millions of records and with some wide filter query its taking too long even with specifying size=200. Meaning its trying to find all matching records from 550 millions and then doing ranking of those.. I want to make query faster..

Comment: I think so you focusing in wrong direction. You should check why it is running slow insted of minimizing count. How many data node you have ? how many shards you have configired ? how much memory allocated on each node ? How you are executing query to elasticsearch , is it from java or any other language client or curl ? is there any netowork latency delay ? and so on... there are so many things you need to check for slow query. You can raise seperate question for same with detials and your actual query.

Comment: Query is the same as provided in the main question. We have 7 nodes.. each node having 2 cpu and 16 GB RAM.. there is no network latency delay..I am executing query from kibana dev tools.

Comment: How many shards and replicas you have ?